# Shiny DT and user form

Tags: shiny, r-markdown, shinydashboard, dt, rnotebook

I have worked on this google form from a shiny example, it has expanded and I would like to sort the numeric inputs and to show when the users save the data the last ID= rowname= entry, the other numeric variables are obvious. you can see my fail at the server, also if someone knows how to run the next chunk after closing shiny I would be grateful.

Also sorry for the Portuguese, if you want me to translate something in the form box feel free to ask.

````
---
title: "R Notebook"
output: html_notebook
---


```{r}
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(DT)
####Functions Used in saving and closing file####
saveData <- function(data) {
  data <- as.data.frame(t(data))
  if (exists("responses")) {
    responses <<- rbind(responses, data)
  } else {
    responses <<- data
  }
  ultimaresposta <<- data
}

loadData <- function() {
  if (exists("responses")) {
    responses
  }
}
# Define the fields we want to save from the form
fields <-
  c(
    "NameDataSet",
    "Uses_dummies",
    "NameDummies",
    "HowToSaveDummies",
    "HowToSaveSimple",
    "WhereToSave",
    "Date",
    "Frequency",
    "Forecast",
    "Confidence_Intervals",
    "Starting_Variable",
    "Finishing_Variable"
  )





ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Forecaster"),
  dashboardSidebar(sidebarMenu(
    menuItem("Dashboard", tabName = "dashboard"),
    menuItem("Raw data View", tabName = "rawdata")
  )),
  # Body do dashboard principal----
  dashboardBody(tabItems(
    tabItem(
      "dashboard",

      fluidPage(div(
        style = 'overflow: auto',
        width = 12,
        DT::dataTableOutput('responses')
      )),

      tags$hr(),
      # soh funciona

      div(
        style = 'overflow: auto',
        box(
          title = "Title 1",
          width = 12,
          solidHeader = TRUE,
          status = "primary",
          fluidPage(fluidRow(
            column(
              6,

              selectInput(
                'NameDataSet',
                'Nome dos dados',
                multiple = FALSE,
                Filter(function(x)
                  is.data.frame(get(x)), ls())
              ),

              checkboxInput("Uses_dummies", "Vamos usar Dummies?", FALSE),

              conditionalPanel(
                condition = "input.Uses_dummies == true",
                selectInput(
                  'NameDummies',
                  'Nome das Dummies',
                  multiple = FALSE,
                  Filter(function(x)
                    is.data.frame(get(x)), ls())
                )
              ),

              conditionalPanel(
                condition = "input.Uses_dummies == true",
                textInput(
                  "HowToSaveDummies",
                  "Como Vamos Chamar essa regressao com dummies?, tem que terminar com .csv",
                  "exemplodesalvardummies.csv"
                )
              ),

              conditionalPanel(
                condition = "input.Uses_dummies == false",
                textInput(
                  "HowToSaveSimple",
                  "Como Vamos Chamar essa regressao simples?, tem que terminar com .csv?",
                  "exemplodesalvarsimples.csv"
                )
              ),

              textInput(
                "WhereToSave",
                "Onde vamos salvar suas regressoes pode ignorar",
                "~/R"
              ),

              dateInput(
                'Date',
                label = "Quando Foi o primeiro dia dos seus dados?",
                value = Sys.Date(),
                format = "dd/mm/yy",
                language = "pt-BR"
              )
            ),

            column(
              6,

              numericInput("Frequency", "Qual eh a frequencia do seus dados?", value = 12),

              numericInput("Forecast", "Quantos periodos de forecast?", value = 12),

              textInput(
                "Confidence_Intervals",
                "qual sao os intervalos de confianca que voce gostaria? Dica deixe 0 para nao colocar nenhum",
                "80,95"
              ),

              numericInput(
                "Starting_Variable",
                "Qual a primeira coluna que vamos usar no forecast?",
                value = 1
              ),

              numericInput(
                "Finishing_Variable",
                "Qual a ultima coluna que vamos usar no forecast?:Dica se deixar no default vamos usar todas as variaveis",
                value = 10000
              ),

              actionButton("submit", "Salvar"),



              bootstrapPage(
                tags$button(
                  id = 'close',
                  type = "button",
                  class = "btn action-button",
                  onclick = "setTimeout(function(){window.close();},500);",
                  # close browser
                  "Close window"
                )
              )
            )
          ))
        )
      )
    ),

    tabItem("rawdata",
            fluidPage(
              selectInput(
                'df_picker',
                'Pick dataframe',
                Filter(function(x)
                  is.data.frame(get(x)), ls())
              ),
              DT::dataTableOutput("df", width = 300)
            ))
  ))
)
#Server
server = function(input, output, session) {
  # Whenever a field is filled, aggregate all form data
  formData <- reactive({
    data <- sapply(fields, function(x)
      input[[x]])
    data
  })

  # When the Submit button is clicked, save the form data
  observeEvent(input$submit, {
    saveData(formData())
  })

  # Show the previous responses
  # (update with current response when Submit is clicked)
  output$responses <- DT::renderDataTable({
    input$submit
    options(DT.options = list(
      pageLength = 1
    ))

    loadData()

  }, colnames = c('ID' = 1), filter = ("top"),as.numeric(1:12))
  #Data table for  view
  output$df <- DT::renderDataTable({
    get(input$df_picker)
  })

  # stop shiny
  observe({
    if (input$close > 0)
      stopApp()
  })

}

#### Preview the UI in the console(Shiny App)####
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)

```
````

Answer (score 0):

If i understand you right, you need to change your submit part in server to something like that:

```
# When the Submit button is clicked, save the form data
  observeEvent(input$submit, {
    saveData(formData())
    updateSelectInput(
      session = session,
      inputId = "df_picker",
      choices = names(which(unlist(eapply(.GlobalEnv,is.data.frame))))
    )
  })
```

So as you see, you need update your input, also i changes code that get dataframes, with your variant that not work..

Comment: Sorry but I dont get what your suggestion is doing, the new part is updateSelectInput(
      session = session,
      inputId = "df_picker",
      choices = names(which(unlist(eapply(.GlobalEnv,is.data.frame)))) and it just doesnt add anything to the code, I already have a way of identifing objects in the global enviroment it is on the raw data view tab, maybe I switched the wrong server function, could you explain your solution?

Comment: I have no idea why your way work on second start but not work in first after submitting data. If i use updateSelectInput with "choices" as you do - it do not work.

Comment: You mean why it doesnt show the DT? well  I used this function loadData <- function() {
  if (exists("responses")) {
    responses
  } If you mean the second tab on the view data, you need to close shiny in order to store things locally, so it will never as far as I know show the ultimaresposta/responses on the first time, because they are still on the responsive state.